# Bash, How to fix array processing, which only works with positive fieldindex?

Tags: arrays, bash

The following is a code example of the question which numbers can be generated in an adjustable range. The range can be set so that only positive, only negative or positive and negative numbers can be output.

In the example, the output numbers are passed to an array and when the array is output, the number of times each number occurs is output.

In the example, the processing by the array only works for positive numbers, which is probably due to the fact that a bash array can only have a positive and no negative field index.

```
#!/bin/bash

ug=0   # lower limit, positive is working, negative give error 
og=50  # upper limit
n=50   # count of numbers

distr=()
for (( i=1; i<=n; i++ )); do # count of numbers
    rnd=$(( RANDOM % ( og - ug + 1 ) + ug )) # create a number from a range
    # echo $rnd
    distr["$rnd"]=$(( distr["rnd"] + 1 ))
done         
echo

for (( i=1; i<=n; i++ )); do
    echo "$i" "${distr[$i]}"
done
echo

sleep 30
```

How can the described problem be solved?

Remark:

- Its known its possible to replace the RANDOM by SRANDOM if available or use other methodes like shuff and so on. The question is primary related on the array problem.

Comment: Use an associative array instead?

Comment: Just wondering about the second loop. Shouldn't that be `(( i=ug; i<=og; i++ ))` instead of `( i=1; i<=n; i++ ))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Associative arrays allow arbitrary strings as indices.
Here, I also took the liberty to change your 2nd loop to `(( i=ug; i<=og; i++ ))`, which seemed more reasonable.

```
#!/bin/bash  
ug=0  # lower limit
og=50 # upper limit
n=50  # count of numbers
declare -A distr=()
for (( i=1; i<=n; i++ )); do
    (( rnd = RANDOM % (og-ug+1) + ug ))
    (( distr[$rnd]++ ))
done
for (( i=ug; i<=og; i++ )); do
  echo "$i ${distr[$i]}"
done
```

Note that `RANDOM % ...` can be at most `32767` and is biased towards smaller numbers if the divisor isn't a power of two.

By the way: You can replace the whole script by something like

```
seq "$ug" "$og" | shuf -rn "$n" | sort -n | uniq -c
```

even though that leaves out numbers that were never randomly chosen.